# How can access browser history within react shepherd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use [React Shepherd](https://github.com/shipshapecode/react-shepherd) to create a walkthrough for my application.

I can't seem to find anything that explains how to switch routes within the tour. window.location.replace = "/someurl" refreshes the page and kills the tour completely. I am trying to achieve something along the lines of this

*History.js*

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

*steps.js*

```
import hist from "./History";

const Steps = [
    {
    //...
    when: {
      hide: () => {
          hist.push("/someurl");
      },
    },
  },
//...
]
export default Steps;
```

*App.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
//...
import Steps from "./Steps";
import hist from "./History";
import "shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css";

const tourOptions = {
  defaultStepOptions: {
    cancelIcon: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    classes: "shepherd-theme-custom",
  },
  useModalOverlay: true,
};

const App = () => {

  return (
      <Router history={hist}>
         <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
         <ShepherdTour steps={Steps} tourOptions={tourOptions}>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/*" component={Main} />
          </ShepherdTour>
      </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When the steps' hide function is called, the url path is switched but the page is not rendered. I am wondering if I am using react-router wrong or is there a different way to go about this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import history from "./History";` ?

Comment: I have access to the history object so the import is fine. It seems to be trying to push the new route since the url in the browser changes but the page itself does not render @PeterDarmis

Comment: `history.push()` from what i read here https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#historypushto-to-state-state is adding the url to the stack so shouldn't you also add the `history.location` in your script https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#historylocation. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: @PeterDarmis Thanks for the response. I have tried `history.location` as well with the same result. I am also using history.push in another page of my application which is working just fine I believe the issue may be tied to React Shepherd in some way.

Comment: You might try wrapping the routes in a `Switch`, to ensure that there is no issue w/ `exact` and the `/*` path

Comment: @nrako ok thanks, I put the switch in still no luck though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this actually had nothing to do with `React Shepherd` at all, this was purely a React Router issue. I mistakenly nested two `BrowserRouter`'s since it was also accidentally included in my `Main` component. Once removed the application navigates with custom history file just fine.